# Dúvida sobre SQL Injection/mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, sql-injection

Estou com dúvidas sobre SQL Injection em PHP. Eu tenho uma classe que tem o objeto usuário, e aí tem nome, idade, etc.

Depois eu coloco na variável `query` algo como:

```
insert into tb_usuarios(nome)values('$this->nome');
```

Com certeza tem risco de sofrer SQL injection né? Eu li sobre `mysqli_real_escape_string` e dizem que não é totalmente seguro.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 0):

A forma para escapar string é dependendo de qual método você está utilizando para inserir os dados no banco.

Se for PDO, é colocando valores em `bind`:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_usuarios (nome) VAUES(:nome);");
$stmt->bindValue(":nome", $this->nome);
$stmt->prepare();
```

Caso seja a classe `mysqli()`, você deve utilizar assim:

```
$nome = $conn->real_escape_string($this->nome);
$conn->query("INSERT INTO tb_usuarios (nome) VAUES('$nome');");
```